# Connection between Lame equation with Weierstrass and elliptic sine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions

Lame function is the solution of the following equation,
$$\frac{d^2w}{dz^2}+\left(A+B\wp(z)\right)w=0,$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants and $\wp(z)$ is the Weierstrass elliptic function. Wiki says that the most important case corresponds to $B\wp(z)=-\kappa^2\mathrm{sn}^2(\kappa,z)$, where $\mathrm{sn}(\kappa,z)$ is the elliptic sine function. Moreover, the Lame equation with elliptic sine function can be quite simply transformed into the Mathieu equation by setting $\kappa\rightarrow 0^{+}$, which gives
$$\kappa^2\mathrm{sn}^2(\kappa,z)=\kappa^2\sin z+\mathcal{O}(\kappa^3).$$

I would like to understand the following:

1. **Is it possible to obtain the elliptic sine function from the Weierstrass elliptic function?**
2. **Is it possible to obtain the sine/cosine function from the Weierstrass elliptic function?**

I have a feeling that it is tightly related to the Inozemtsev limit, which corresponds to setting one of the periods in Weierstrass function to infinity with some additional tricks.

Comment: There is an answer for your first question [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/23.6).

Comment: Answer for second question [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/WeierstrassP/03/01/01/0002/), except for $\cot(z)$